# Pressure at same horizontal level of fluids in the arrangement given

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Suppose, we have an arrangement as shown in the diagram(same fluid):
[image]

Pressure at point A is *Pa*= Atmospheric Pressure (*Patm*). Similarly, Pressure at point C is *Pc* = *Patm*.

We have been told that pressure at same horizontal level within same static fluid, is equal. Therefore, Pressure at point B (*Pb*) should also be equal to *Patm*. But there's no atmosphere above it, what I mean is that it has a solid rigid surface above it so Pressure just below (i.e., at *Pb*) should be 0, right? But it isn't like that.

Please help me find out what I'm missing here and where my concept is flawed.
To be precise, I want intuitional answers explaining the forces involved and something like that.
Note: The diagram I have made might not be physically possible but just try to understand my main question.

Answer (score 0):

I think looking it approach that point might help.

If there was a little gap between fluid and B lid we can either have:

- there's some air
- there is not

If there is, that air is trapped. If you pour more water it will no longer be at the same level because you increase pressure on that tiny air. The more water you pour the smaller the volume of that air gets, and thus the higher the pressure of that air becomes.

If there is no air(aka void), the water gets pulled up since there's no pressure above. This will once again lead to a situation where you don't have all the water at the same height. This time the A and C column will get lower than the B column(assuming they all started the same, with a gap of air with height h under the B lid).

Now, your situation is the second. Suppose there's void. A and C water flows into the B column. Thus making the B column squeeze under the B lid with the same pressure as Patm minus a contribute due to having different smaller heights on the side(which will work as a "pump" trying to pull away water from the B column. If you pour enough water to reach equal level of the three columns you can now see that there is indeed pressure under the B lid.

You can also see this dynamically in a more straightforward way. On A,C column there is a force pushing down. This force pushes the molecules next to them, all the way to the water under B lid. For it to be at equilibrium Patm * A= Fg (which is not the case). So you need another force, this force is pB*A)

Comment: So it's like if *Pb* =0 we have F=(*Patm* + *dgh*)(Area) (d=density, h=height of column) (if we consider one column of water), pushing it up against the rigid end at B. Such that for the system to remain at equilibrium in the given arrangement, the end at B applies reaction(of pushing of water column from below ) to the water below it , making *Pb* ≠ 0 (*Pb* would be equal to *Patm* if i am not wrong). 

Did i get it correctly?

Comment: If I got what you meant yes, if it's only 1 column it'd actually be Patm-dgh since the weight of the column goes down, and the push of Patm goes up. But I'm not sure I got this second case. But regardless it seems you got the point I was making

Comment: By one column of water i meant, we are taking into account only one column for writing force equations and other would be symmetrical(there would be both in the scenario) PS.i just wrote water instead of fluid

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is no cover on the top cover of B. The air is pushing down the water on B with the same pressure of the top part of A and C (atmospheric pressure).

Now, suppose that a massless solid cover is placed over B. It will be in equilibrium with atmospheric pressure forcing it downward, and the reaction from the fluid forcing it upward.

For a real massive cover, its weight must be supported by the vertical solid walls of the container. But the pair: atmospheric pressure and reaction from the fluid remains.